# ¿Cómo eliminar el primer paréntesis de una lista con regex?

Tags: regex, ms-word, traducción

Una amiga estudia traducción y le han pedido traducir en Microsoft Word un documento del inglés al español. Las listas en el documento en inglés son del tipo `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, `...`. Mientras que en español deben ser del tipo `1)`, `2)`, `3)`, `a)`, `b)`, `c)`, `...`.

Hemos probado varias expresiones pero ninguna funciona. La expresión no debe eliminar un *match* entre paréntesis, si dentro de este hay una frase. De este modo, la expresión debería hacer esto:

```
Hi. My name is Alice (obviously my name is Alice). Here's the shopping list:

(1) sugar
(2) bread
(3) eggs

Be sure to:

(a) be careful
(b) wash your hands
(c) have social distance
```

```
Hola. Me llamo Alice (obviamente me llamo Alice). Aquí tienes la lista de la compra:

1) azúcar
2) pan
3) huevos

Asegúrate de:

a) cuidarte
b) lavarte las manos
c) tener distancia social
```

¿Alguna idea?

**AÑADO**

Hemos utilizado las siguientes expresiones pero no nos funciona:

```
(\([A-Z]|[a-z]|\d+\))

\((*)\) con sustitución \1)

([(])/g

\(([a-z][0-9])\g
```

Comment: Ya sabes que tienes que aportar el código en que has trabajado hasta ahora. Además, ¿es C# o Python?

Comment: No hay código. Eso mismo es lo que buscamos. Es regex de Microsoft Word pero he puesto las categorías de `c#`y `python` porque también se usa regex en esos lenguajes. Añado: he editado la pregunta con las expresiones que hemos probado y que no funcionan.

Comment: @ortiz, no utilizo `MS Word` pero se me ocurre que podrías usar esta RegEx `/\((\d|\w)+\) /g` y sustitución `$1)`